# Not all arguments converted during string formatting. Why am I having error

Tags: python

```
l=[[1,2,3,4], (2,3,4,5,6,), (3,4,5,6,7), set([23,4,5,45,4,4,5,45,45,4,5]), {'K1': "sudh", "k2": "ineuron", "k3":"kumar", 3:6,7:8}, ["ineuron", "datasience"]]
for i in l:
    if type(i)==list:
        for j in i:
            if j % 2!=0:
                print(j)
```

Why am I having error "not all arguments converted during string formatting"?

Comment: What is the desired output? Your code will evaluate `"ineuron" % 2`, and python will think that you are trying to format the string `"ineuron"`. Note that `%` is a modulo operator as you intended, and also a string formatting operator.

Comment: What do you expect: `j % 2` to be when `j` is a string?

Comment: So I have to write if type(j)==int:
 j%2!==0. Right?

Comment: @ArijitKoley: Yes, if that's what you want.

Comment: Yes Got the output. Cheers!

Comment: @ArijitKoley - try to run this program in https://pythontutor.com/   then debugging is super easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to perform a modulo operation on a string:

```
"ineuron" % 2
```

The last element of `l` list is `["ineuron", "datasience"]`. It passes the if statement, and then `j` becomes `"ineuron"` and you get an error.

Comment: Yes, the OP thinks they want to perform modulo arithmetic. Python thinks the OP wants to perform string formatting.

Answer (score 1):

You've to check if the list contains strings because you can't divide strings.

```py
l=[[1,2,3,4], (2,3,4,5,6,), (3,4,5,6,7), set([23,4,5,45,4,4,5,45,45,4,5]), {'K1': "sudh", "k2": "ineuron", "k3":"kumar", 3:6,7:8}, ["ineuron", "datasience"]]
for i in l:
    if type(i)==list:
        for j in i:
            if isinstance(j, str) == False and j % 2!=0:
                print(j)
```

Comment: `isinstance(j, str) == False` should be `not isinstance(j, str)`